# Prepend text to specific line numbers with variables

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I have spent hours trying to solve this. There are a bunch of answers as to how to prepend to all lines or specific lines but not with a variable text and a variable number.

```
while [ $FirstVariable -lt $NextVariable ]; do
  #sed -i "$FirstVariables/.*/$FirstVariableText/" "$PWD/Inprocess/$InprocessFile"
  cat "$PWD/Inprocess/$InprocessFile" | awk 'NR==${FirstVariable}{print "$FirstVariableText"}1' > "$PWD/Inprocess/Temp$InprocessFile"
  FirstVariable=$[$FirstVariable+1]
done
```

Essentially I am looking for a particular string delimiter and then figuring out where the next one is and appending the first result back into the following lines... Note that I already figured out the logic I am just having issues prepending the line with the variables.

Example:

This >

```
Line1:
1
2
3

Line2:
1
2
3
```

Would turn into >

```
Line1:
Line1:1
Line1:2
Line1:3

Line2:
Line2:1
Line2:2
Line2:3
```

Comment: please edit your Q to include values for variable `$NextVariable` . But this can all be done in one `awk` script. Look at the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . AND is there really a blank line between the `Line1` and `Line2` sections? If not, then please edit your sample data to accurately show the data. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all that using below awk one liner.

Assuming your pattern starts with `Line`, then the below script can be used.

```
> awk '{if ($1 ~ /Line/ ){var=$1;print $0;}else{ if ($1 !="")print var $1}}' $PWD/Inprocess/$InprocessFile

Line1:
Line1:1
Line1:2
Line1:3
Line2:
Line2:1
Line2:2
Line2:3
```

Here is how the above script works:

If the first record contains word `Line` then it is copied into an awk variable  `var`. From next word onwards, if the record is not empty, the newly created `var` is appended to that record and prints it producing the desired result.

If you need to pass the variables dynamically from shell to awk you can use `-v` option. Like below:

```
awk -v var1=$FirstVariable -v var2=$FirstVariableText 'NR==var{print var2}1' > "$PWD/Inprocess/Temp$InprocessFile"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not static and is line specific. I have additional logic to identify the line numbers which go through the while statement counting the lines until the next issue. The issue is placing the variables for a unique line number with the variable $FirstVariable, copying the contents of that line and prepending the unique content of $FirstVariableText

Comment: @JamesCarlin If you need to pass the variables dynamically from shell to awk you can use -v option. Please see the edited answer, if that is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The way you addressed the problem is by parsing everything both with bash and awk to process the file. You make use of bash to extract a line, and then use awk to manipulate this one line. The whole thing can actually be done with a single awk script:

```
awk '/^Line/{str=$1; print; next}{print (NF ? str $0 : "")}' inputfile > outputfile
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"}{gsub(FS,OFS $1)}1' inputfile > outputfile
```